# How long are the Gates of Justice (i.e. 正義の門) in One piece?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, there are giant gates protecting the entrance to Enies Lobby, Impel Down, and Marineford. They look about as long as an average giant (巨人) above sea level.

But, I was wondering how long are they below sea level. For instance, **can Jinbe or any other fishmen swim under it?**

> I mean it can't stretch up to the sea floor and fishmen can swim up to 10000m deep. Or does it?